# Issues with images showing on PC but not on mobile

Tags: html, css, templates

The CSS is not working. The text on certain images shows on PC but not on the mobile version of the site.

The site is [www.greencitylandscapes.co.uk](https://www.greencitylandscapes.co.uk) and the home page has 3 images with text visible on the PC version, but these are not visible in the mobile version.

The images appear but without text.
How can I fix this problem?

```
/**
 *  Master Slider
 *  Default Skin
 */

.ms-skin-default .ms-slide .ms-slide-vpbtn,
.ms-skin-default .ms-video-btn{
    width: 50px;
    height: 51px;
    background: url(light-skin-1.png) no-repeat -14px -150px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-slide .ms-slide-vcbtn {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: url(light-skin-1.png) no-repeat -24px -28px;
    top: 18px;
    right: 30px;
}

/* controls */

.ms-skin-default .ms-nav-next,
.ms-skin-default .ms-nav-prev {
    width: 30px;
    background: url(light-skin-1.png);
    background-position: -89px -26px;
    height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 110;
}
.ms-skin-default .ms-nav-next {
    right: 30px;
    left: auto;
    background-position: -89px -103px;
}



.ms-skin-default .ms-bullet {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: url(light-skin-1.png) no-repeat;
    margin: 4px;
    background-position: -34px -117px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-bullet-selected {
    background-position: -34px -84px;
}


.ms-skin-default .ms-time-bar {
    height: 3px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
}


.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 210;
    cursor: auto;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-top .ms-tooltip-arrow,
.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-bottom .ms-tooltip-arrow{
    border-left: solid 10px transparent;
    border-right: solid 10px transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-top .ms-tooltip-arrow{
    border-top: solid 10px;
    border-top-color: silver;
    border-top-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.88);
    bottom: -10px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-bottom .ms-tooltip-arrow {
    border-bottom: solid 10px;
    border-bottom-color: silver;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.88);
    top: -10px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-right .ms-tooltip-arrow,
.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-left .ms-tooltip-arrow{
    border-top: solid 10px transparent;
    border-bottom: solid 10px transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-right .ms-tooltip-arrow{
    border-right: solid 10px;
    border-right-color: silver;
    border-right-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.88);
    left: -10px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-left .ms-tooltip-arrow {
    border-left: solid 10px;
    border-left-color: silver;
    border-left-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.88);
    right: -10px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-point {cursor: pointer;}
.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-point .ms-point-center {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px; 
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: solid 2px #BBB;
    background: white;
    margin: -8px 0 0 -8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 105;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-point .ms-point-border {
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px; 
    background: black;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
    margin: -11px 0 0 -11px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 15px;
    
    animation: point-anim 1.5s infinite ;
    -moz-animation: point-anim 1.5s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: point-anim 1.5s infinite;
    -o-animation: point-anim 1.5s infinite;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip {
    max-width:200px;
}

.ms-skin-default .ms-tooltip-cont {
    padding: 10px;
    background: silver;
    background: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.88);
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0px white;
    margin-left: -1px;
}

/* retina */
@media 
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    
    .ms-skin-default .ms-slide .ms-slide-vpbtn,
    .ms-skin-default .ms-video-btn,
    .ms-skin-default .ms-slide .ms-slide-vcbtn,
    .ms-skin-default .ms-nav-next,
    .ms-skin-default .ms-nav-prev,
    .ms-skin-default .ms-bullet{
        background-image:url(light-skin-1-retina.png);
        background-size: 152px 225px;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hey, Julian. I'd like to help, but it's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish without some `html` or visuals. The URL you included, doesn't seem to do what you described, so I can't debug it. Please add some more information.

Comment: Do you mean the text which appears on hover on the images near the bottom of the page? This seems to work in Chrome emulating mobile devices so can you describe more what the problem is/what devices it's not working on etc.

Comment: Hi all .Basically on the pc version of the site www.greencitylandscapes.co.uk there are 3 images at the top of the home page. They have text on them on the pc version, however wheni open the same page on a mobile phone the 3 images appear but not the text on the images